# Cross Domain AJAX request using JSONP not working :(

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I was told that a good way to get information from another server is done by using JSONP.

Resources on this topic aren't very high, as I tried researching about it, and I looked for examples, but most were just copy pastes and they didn't work for me.

I will paste my code and briefly explain what I'm doing.

So this is just the relevant section of my code, what I did before was I parsed the user form and assigned the values into the JSON object. Then I'm just trying to pass this data to my server (not the same domain as this data is being sent from.). I won't lie, I have no idea what I'm doing in this snippet of code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
            var myJSON = {"name": name, "cc": creditNo, "cvv": cvv, "month": month, "year": year};

            /*
            * Now we want to send data to server via AJAX
            */

            var showTemp = function(result){ 
                $("#ajaxDiv").html(result);
            }


            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "url/callback=showTemp",
                async: false,
                jsonpCallback: 'myJSON',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json) {
                   console.dir(json.sites);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                   console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are naming twice your callback, showTemp and myJson.

try this and make sure that your response is padded on the same named callback, in this case myJSON

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "url/?callback=?",
                async: false,
                jsonpCallback: 'myJSON',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json) {
                   console.dir(json.sites);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                   console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
```